# How can I scale the icon of a Spark button?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a Spark button with an icon, and I want to be able to scale it, as with an Image component, but I can't find any property for that. Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to scale it?  Do you want to scale the icon?  Or the image?  Is there any reason the scale9Grid / scaleX / scaleY / scaleZ properties won't work?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scale9Grid

Comment: Are these properties supposed to scale the image, not the component itself?

Comment: If you set these properties on the image; they will scale the image.  If you set them on the component; they will scale the component.

Comment: But the image is set by using the icon property of the Button component, so I can't apply it on the image.

Comment: So,set the properties on the iconDisplay skin pat that represents the image: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#SkinPartSummary

Answer (score 0):

You could look into Button Class, and then write a custom Class extends Button and implement what you want.

I remember that the icon is displaied by BitmapImage, you could get it's reference and then scale that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale the icon; but not the button; you can do so by accessing the properties directly on the [iconDisplay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ButtonBase.html#SkinPart%3aiconDisplay) skin part:

```
myButtonInstance.iconDisplay.scaleX = 2;
myButtonInstance.iconDisplay.scaleY = 2;
myButtonInstance.iconDisplay.scaleZ = 2;
```

The properties used for scaling are [scaleX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html#scaleX), [scaleY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html#scaleY), and [scaleZ](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html#scaleX).  The BitMapImage also has a property called [scaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html#scaleMode)